# setState is not calling when Navigating to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am checking the connectivity using `Connectivity().checkConnectivity()` it is working but  the `setState()` is not calling when I navigate to this page.

To navigate to main page to another page I am using `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => search()));`

and here is my next page

```
 class search extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_searchState createState() => _searchState();
}

class _searchState extends State<search> {
  List<filter> _list = [];
  List<filter> to_display = [];

bool isoffline;

Future<void> connectivity() async {
var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
  setState(() {
    isoffline = true;
  });

  print("connected");
 } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  setState(() {
    isoffline = true;
  });
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
  print("connected");
 } else {
  setState(() {
    isoffline = false;
  });
  print(
      "dissconneteddsfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdsfsd");
 }
}

Future _future;
@override
void initState() {
 mylist().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _list = to_display = value;
  });
});

connectivity();
print("value${isoffline}"); // this value is on null 
_future = data();
super.initState();
}
```

`print("value${isoffline}");` // this value is on null

Comment: setState is not calling? what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to set `isoffline=false` when no Internet connection

Comment: The print statement is working fine but the `bool` value not changing

Comment: Okay fine, then i think you need to call connectivity(); this method in your build method like   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) connectivity(); {  .....  }  this. Because initState is only call once

Comment: I am getting value like this `value null`

Comment: But it is working fine in `main.dart` page

Comment: Okay means you want to call this method continuously when the user reaches this page right?

Comment: not continuously only once time but the problem is  the `bool` value not changing

Comment: If possible can i add one answer it may help you if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function connectivity is an asynchronous function. You are calling the function and immediately checking the boolean value, that's why you are getting null. You have to wait till the execution, either by using await or then syntax.

```dart
connectivity().then((value) {
   print("value ${isoffline}");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `connectivity();` method is `async` which mean it will require some time to complete.

Now when `init` method is called it executes `connectivity();` and then immediately executes `print("value${isoffline}");` now the value for `isoffline` initially is `null`, hence `null` printed

solution is either you put `print("value${isoffline}");` in `connectivity();` method or try to add it after `build` method.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  connectivity();
  print("value${isoffline}");
  return YourWidget();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir but  I did not want to check connectivity continuously